# Paypal sandbox credit card details not working

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I generated a Sandbox 'buyer' account in the paypal developer site which automated a credit card no. and expiry date. However this does not seem to work as all I get is a message when testing the transaction:

"You cannot use an email address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in. If you don't, please change the email address or card number and try again"

If I try to login to paypal using the fake email and password created for the buyer account that also fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Os

Comment: Are you sure the login is failing? I just did it with the buyer account that was automatically generated for me and it worked quite well.

Answer (score 8):

If you are needing a test credit card number to use during the checkout process through sandbox, you can either log into one of your existing accounts and start the process of adding a credit card.  This will pre populate the card number for you.  Just copy down the card number and do not add it to the account so that it is not linked.  As for the expiration date you can use any valid future date, and and you can use 123 for the CVV2 code.  Otherwise you can also use some of the test credit card numbers on this page [here](https://www.ccaples.com/index.php/misc/tools-and-stuff/cc-num-gen) for testing with the sandbox.  Each time the page is refreshed, new card numbers should be generated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've kind of got it working now using the random generated credit card numbers at the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've kind of got it working now using the random generated credit card numbers at the link you provided. Seems a bit weird though. If I pay by fake credit card each time I have to use a new credit card number and a new email address. The pay pal email address I'am requested to create on the check out page of Sandbox appends itself to the Sandbox accounts. If I then test again through Sandbox using the same email and credit card number I get a red error message saying 'cannot use email or card numbers associated with this account',stupid, unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: You should be able to use the card numbers over as well as the email addresses, unless you are creating an account each time during checkout where you are registering that card and email address.  Depending on the country of the accounts being used here, you may have an option to complete transaction without using a PayPal account or creating one.  I would have to see the checkout and walk through it, and need the email addresses of the buyer and seller accounts to take a look at them.

Comment: Not working at all. This answer is too old